# Error on hidden field "Object reference not set to an instance of an object. "

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show a message to the user, but I am getting an error on this line:

```
HF_Reg_Id.Value = Session["Reg_id"].ToString();
```

where HF_Reg_Id is a hidden field.

Markup:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GV_Contact" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Contact_id" AutoGenerateColumns="False"AllowPaging="True"AllowSorting="True">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt"></AlternatingRowStyle> 
    <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Contact_id" HeaderText="ID" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Reg_id" HeaderText="Register ID" /> 
           <asp:BoundField DataField="txtName" HeaderText="Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="txtBody" HeaderText="Message" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="MsgType" HeaderText="Message Type" /> 
    </Columns>  
</asp:GridView>
```

Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HF_Reg_Id.Value = Session["Reg_id"].ToString();
        BindGrid1();
    }
    public DataSet viewContactMsg()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "Set_Field_User_Msg";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Reg_id", HF_Reg_Id.Value);
        cmd.Connection = con;

        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ad.SelectCommand = cmd;
        ad.Fill(ds);

        return ds;
    }
    public void BindGrid1()
    {
        DataSet ds = viewContactMsg();

        GV_Contact.DataSource = ds;
        GV_Contact.DataBind();
    }

create PROC Set_Field_User_Msg @Reg_id as int As Begin Select
Contact_id,Reg_id,Email,txtName,txtBody,MsgType from Contact where
Reg_id=@Reg_id order by Reg_id desc End
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please summarize your question in the title and add your descriptive question with details in the body.

Comment: What line is throwing the error?  There are several references to HF_Reg_Id, which I assume is your hidden field.  Also, why are you showing us the markup for a GridView if the error is related to a hidden field?

Comment: Are you sure that your session is carrying a value?

Comment: this line throwing  error HF_Reg_Id.Value = Session["Reg_id"].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

You should check to see if the session exists, and if session has that key before assigning it.

```
if(Session != null && Session["Reg_id"] != null)
{
     HF_Reg_Id.Value = Session["Reg_id"].ToString();
}
```